# Combine several bitmaps into (TrueType) font

Tags: fonts, truetype, pixel-fonts, bitmap-fonts

I have several (~200) small bitmap files with glyph images. How can I combine them to a single bitmap font file?

Actually, I need a TrueType font created from these bitmaps (with no curves, smoothing, vectorization or any transformations). It's a designer 'pixel' font, so it should have rough pixel edges and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://chris.pirillo.com/how-to-create-your-own-truetype-font-for-free/) or [fontforge](http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/) is of any help.

Comment: I've installed FontForge but couldn't find bath editor or bitmap import there